# laravel 5.7 : how to filter search?

Tags: laravel, search, filter

I'm trying to make an advanced search by multiple inputs :

```
$orders = new Order;

        if ($request->has('client_id')) {
            $orders->where('client_id' ,$request->client_id);
        }

        if ($request->has('city_id')) {
            $orders->where('city_id', $request->city_id);
        }

        dd($orders->get());
```

but this code returns all database records.
And if i use get method with the query in one line it works just fine!

```
$orders->where('city_id', $request->city_id)->get();
dd($orders);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `$orders = $orders->get();` `dd($orders)`

Comment: didn't work , i solved this by setting the variable $orders for each clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a simple way, just do this

```
$query = Order::query();

if ($request->has('client_id')) {
    $query->where('client_id' ,$request->client_id);
}

if ($request->has('city_id')) {
    $query->where('city_id', $request->city_id);
}

dd($query->get());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set the variable `$order` each time you add the clause e.g:

```
$orders = new Order;

if ($request->has('client_id')) {
     $orders = $orders->where('client_id' ,$request->client_id);
}

if ($request->has('city_id')) {
    $orders = $orders->where('city_id', $request->city_id);
}
 // then run $orders->get(); or other stuff
```

The new values of `$orders` would have been updated accordingly.

Its quite interesting that way you declared the model caused the problem. By creating a new instance of `Order` using `new` keyword, the model has not recognize  the default query builder (for some reason), meaning that `dump()`ing the model there's no wheres array to push the new where into.

Other ways you could do it is to have an initial query e.g

```
Order::whereNotNull('id');

//Otherwise as suggested use `->query()` or `newQuery()`
```

> Mind you `query()` is like an alias of `newQuery()` except that `query()` creates **a fresh** instance of the model before calling `newQuery()`.

You can instead use `getQuery()` to retrieve the `$query` property of the model instead of the two as you don't need to re-instantiate the builder.
Therefore, you can have:

```
 $orders = Order::getQuery();

if ($request->has('client_id')) {
     $orders->where('client_id' ,$request->client_id);
}

if ($request->has('city_id')) {
    $orders->where('city_id', $request->city_id);
}
 // then run $orders->get(); or other stuff
```

> PS: I tested this on L5.4

Answer (score 1):

try to initialize the query

```
$query = Order::select("*");

if ($request->has('client_id')) {
   $query->where('client_id' ,$request->client_id);
}

if ($request->has('city_id')) {
   $query->where('city_id', $request->city_id);
}

dd($query->get());
```